# How can I check whether an jQuery GET returned any HTML?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I currently have the following Javascript, and I am not sure what I should put in for the commented area to check if the get returned any HTML?

```
$('#load-more').click(function() {
  $.get('/load/friend/2'/, function(data) {

    // If there is HTML returned, then $('#load-friend').append(data)
    // Else $('#load-global').append(data)

   });
});
```

The get queries `/load/friend/2`, which returns an `HttpResponse` object in Django that was rendered with `render_to_response(template, context, RequestContext(request))`.

The Django template looks like the following:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
  // Code
{% endfor %}
```

So when $.get retrieves /load/friend/2 and reviews = [], I believe it should return an empty HTML document?

Comment: What would it be if it is _not_ html (given that either way you seem to want to append it one element or another)?

Comment: Clarified.  It should return blank HTML?

Comment: If it is returning "blank" as in literally an empty string then just test for that: `if (data===") ...` or `if (data.replace(/\s/g,"")==="") ...` if there might be some whitespace - but if it is returning blank why do you want an `else` case to append it to `'#load-global'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Django controller, if `reviews` is empty, return a http status code instead of the view template:

```
if not reviews:
    # 204 = "no content"
    return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

In the JavaScript, use jQuery's general [AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to define the callbacks:

```
$('#load-more').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/load/friend/2',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#load-friend').append(data);
        },
        statusCode: {
            204: function () {
                $('#load-global').append('<p>No reviews found.</p>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```